# Installing the iLBC codec (libilbc) on Mac OS X for use with FFmpeg

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, codec, homebrew

I'm trying to use FFmpeg to encode files with the iLBC codec, e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.wav -ar 8000 -acodec ilbc audio.lbc -y
```

This worked fine on Windows, however on Mac OS X I'm getting the error `Unknown encoder 'ilbc'`.

The [official FFmpeg documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/general.html#libilbc) has this to say about libilbc:

> Go to https://github.com/dekkers/libilbc and follow the instructions for installing the library. Then pass `--enable-libilbc` to configure to enable it.

I've never compiled a library before so I tried my luck editing the brew recipe, adding these lines where appropriate:

```
option "with-libilbc", "Enable iLBC library
args << "--enable-libilbc" if build.with? "libilbc"
```

Then reinstalling ffmpeg with `brew install ffmpeg --with-libilbc`. However, that just causes the build to fail and I don't see any message error pertaining to iLBC. My assumption is that the library is simply missing at this point anyway.

Hence my questions:

- How can I compile the libilbc mentioned in the FFmpeg doc for Mac OS X?
- Can I then connect it to brew somehow so as to rebuild ffmpeg with it?

Comment: FYI, the error messages while building ffmpeg were not helpful quite simply because they were being truncated. Using the `-v` flag fixed that and helped see what the problem was.

Comment: Would you consider making libilbc as a formula, and making that and your changes to ffmpeg a pull request?

Comment: Sure. I've never done it before but I'll try my hand at it.

Comment: Would be nice. I can also try but I don't have so much time at the moment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repository you linked is missing a configure file, even though the installation file mentioned it. This looks like a better repository https://github.com/Distrotech/libilbc-webrtc

so what you do is

```
git clone https://github.com/Distrotech/libilbc-webrtc.git
cd libilbc-webrtc
./configure
make
make install
```

then after don't forget to actually use the option you added in the brew file like so:

```
brew install --with-ilbc -v
```

Comment: Regarding the [libilbc repository](https://github.com/TimothyGu/libilbc) mentioned in the FFmpeg docs: running `autoreconf -fiv` will create the `configure` file.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up of using `ffmpeg` for this. I solved the problem using `afconvert` (included by default on MacOS). For example:

```
afconvert test.mp3 -o test.caf -d ilbc
```

Comment: But the OP specified ffmpeg.

Comment: I solved the issue with the selected answer but I'm glad to know about this alternative.